# Emacs buffer, ansi Sequence & Custom Themes

Tags: emacs, elisp, ansi-escape

Let me have a file like this (^[ is actually escape)

```
^[[0m^[[31;40m This is a Red Foreground On Black Background
^[[0m^[[32;40m This is a Green Foreground on Black Background
^[[0m^[[37;40m This is a White Foreground on Black Background
^[[0m^[[33;40m This is a Yellow Foreground on Black Background
```

Now I open a shell in emacs: [I have...

```
(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on)
```

for ansi color]

and I do "cat file" everything is fine. Lines come colored as I wanted it to be.

Now I do a "load-theme material" [This is a modern "custom theme" which I do not know anything about]. This theme has a grey background.

**Now if I do the same cat file then the background is white. As a matter of fact, the line "This is a White Foreground on Black Background" comes Black on white!!**

**How to solve this? How to make 'cat file' make color encoding irrespective of theme?**